# Try correcting to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'OutlineButton' in flutter 3.0.0. it isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, dart

I've installed `flutter 3.0.0`. Now I'm getting error that `OutlinedButton` isn't defined for the type.

**Error:**

> Method not found: 'OutlineButton'. lib/appUtils/app_utility.dart:233
>
> OutlineButton(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Error: Method not found: 'OutlineButton'. lib/appUtils/app_utility.dart:255
> OutlineButton(
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That widget have been changed to `OutlinedButton`.

```
Old Widget was : OutlineButton
Old Theme was : ButtonTheme
New Widget is : OutlinedButton
New Theme is : OutlinedButtonTheme
```

Here's an example :

```
OutlinedButton(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
        ),
    onPressed: () { dismissDialog(); },
    child: Text('New Outlined Button'),
),
```

Comment: thanks, @Atlas-Pio. and The primary properties in OutlinedButton.styleFrom() can change the splash color. yes thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is a breaking change. And it is listed up top in the breaking changes documentation:

> The FlatButton, RaisedButton and OutlineButton widgets have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

[source](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)